# javascript word in address bar is making my apache web server down

Tags: javascript, php, apache, webserver

I have seen this weirdest issue. My website works well when there is no javascript word in the browser URL and if there is any word in the browser url. like eg. https://www.example.com/?tag=javascript%20statement It first throw error in the console as Error 406 Not acceptable for js files. I have attached the screenshot of request header below. And if i continues to refresh the page by hard reload and clear cache reload. After 5-6 attempts the server goes down for 10-15 min. I am using the shared hosting plan from good hosting provider. I have also posted ticket to them but still they have not resolved it. So please help if anyone has encounter such a issue while working with web server.

Comment: Sounds like your "good" hosting plan has `mod_security` enabled with a broken rule.

Comment: It might not be a good idea to post Basic Auth credentials online, even if it's in an image.

Comment: Ya you are right.  i remove that image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are getting blacklisted by your hosting provider, because (they think) you are trying to abuse XSS. There is no easy solution unfortunately (except for encoding your parameters, or switching to another hosting provider).

Comment: Thanx for reply. But i have tested many websites using this javascript word tag , that whether they goes down or not. But they are working well. Also i have tested this on my friends server it is working fine there to. It means there must be some easy solution for it. If this weird thing has no issue on other server so it must be some problem with my server configuration.

Comment: Did you test many website that use *the same hosting service*?

Comment: no. I have posted the ticket to my hosting provider. They are investing the issue.

Comment: Well, then it is a problem with your hosting provider. As I wrote in my answer, it cannot be fixed easily, except for encoding your parameters, or switching hosting providers.

Comment: thanx daan. I encoded the url parameters. It is working now.

Comment: hi daan . I need to get this solution fixed by hosting provider. Encoding uri parameter solution works when everthing is controlled by the code. But still when i type javascript directly to address bar my server goes down. So anyone can make it down if he knows this thing.

Comment: Hi daan can you provide any solution so that it will be easy for them to work. I dont know why they are not able to solve it yet. I was thinking it is a good hosting provider but this is a serious issue. If any persons hosts e commerce website at my hosting provider his business may suffer bcoz of this problem server down problem.

Comment: Hey vish_php, resolving trouble your hosting provider might be having is hardly your responsibility, let alone mine (in stackoverflow at least, you might want to try your luck in serverfault). Although I don't think the server *really* goes down. My guess is your IP is prevented from accessing it for a couple of minutes. An easy way to check this is by using your phone (WITHOUT WIFI CONNECTION) to check if you can still reach your site, when your computer gets blocked.

Comment: i also thought that only my IP was blocked so i have tested this using different ip address also. Also when i demonstrated this to my hosting provider he was doing the same thing at his end. But when the website was down at his end it was down at my end also. I just discussed this things with my hosting provider they told it was down due mod_security . I told them this is the serious issue. You have to think this problem deeply. Since anyone can attack on your shared hosting websites. If they knows this thing. They told they are working on it and will give solution.

Comment: Ya daan you are right the website was down only for me. Now i told my hosting provider to close the tickete. I can access my website from other network. I have tried to access it from other proxy networks it is working fine. So it was down only for me

Comment: Thanx for your comment so that i understood this problem and closed the tickete. When i discussed with my hosting provider he also believed that sever was down for everyone. We had a very long discussion over this and i have told that all your websites are under attack. So please take this issue on priority. And he was working on it. When i read your comment i understood the problem and closed the tickete. Thanx .

Comment: Glad you were helped by my comments :)

Answer (score 1):

You should encode the URI part. In the php code, you decode it. This way the URI part is escaped and safe to transfer and it will not trigger any security measures. Example, use encodeURIComponent() in javascript before parsing to php and in php, you use urldecode().

Comment: Thanx for the reply. i will try but i have a doubt whether it will work or not because if my web server has a problem with javascript word in the url. So even after using encodeuri the javascript word will be as it is in the encoded string. So it might cause problem again.

Comment: Thanx Werner. Your solution worked. After encodeURI my url parameter became javascript%2520statement. Intially it was javascript%20statement.  Now i have tested my web server with this encodedURI string it is working fine without going down. And thanx to stackoverflow for creating such a wonderful platform. I got solution to my problem within a minute.

Comment: HI werner i need to add more to the solution. Your solution worked no doubt. But it is useful when everthing is done by the code. But still anyone can make my web server down by entering that word tag directly.

Comment: hi werner your solution was also right i have implemented in my website to bypass the security measures of server. but i have marked daan answer correct since here we can mark only one answer correct. Since the website was down only for my IP for 10-15 min. So it is not a serious issue.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, @vish_php!